# Error only on Linux, not on Mac: Got an unexpected keyword argument 'kwargs'

Tags: python, debian, keyword-argument

I wrote a push notification scheduler in python for research, which will handle sending notifications via NODE .js. It works beautifully on my Mac, no problems. I built a server elsewhere to handle the scheduler, since it's always on. The server runs Debian Wheezy, for reasons I'm not in control of. However, whenever I try to run the code, I get:

```
File "scheduler.py", line 148, in send_notifications
    s.enter(5, 1, notification, kwargs={'notify': 'Welcome to the Study!'})
TypeError: enter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kwargs'
```

Still works perfectly on my Mac. I've checked to make sure that all my imported libraries have been downloaded via pip3, but I just can't figure out what my problem is. I've checked out other people with this error on stackoverflow and various other sources, but I wasn't sure that they were having a similar problem to my problem, mostly a class call issue, and I don't think this is that. I've attached the code, although I'm not sure if that helps any. I mean, it's not the cleanest code in the world, but I'm more fluent in mobile dev than python. Any recommendations?

```
import time #this need is obvious 
import datetime as dt
import sched
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from subprocess import call #needed to call terminal commands
#Don't forget to chmod +x this python application so that you can sudo out.

#this order of the notifications that will be run, in an array
listOfNotificationNames = ['weather', 'sched', 'thermo', 'manualKitchen', 'frontDoor', 'garage', 'window', 'solar', 'backDoor', 'garage', 'frontDoor', 
    'manualKitchen', 'solar', 'energyCom', 'alarm', 'weather', 'sched', 'solar', 'manualKitchen', 'thermo', 'frontDoor', 'garage', 'manualKitchen', 
    'autokitchen', 'backDoor', 'frontDoor', 'manualKitchen', 'garage', 'sensor', 'solar', 'window', 'energyCom', 'alarm', 'weather', 'sched', 'thermo', 
    'manualKitchen', 'frontDoor', 'garage', 'tvenergy', 'window', 'garage', 'backDoor', 'solar', 'frontDoor', 'manualKitchen', 'energyCom', 'alarm', 
    'weather', 'sched', 'solar', 'thermo', 'manualKitchen', 'frontDoor', 'manualKitchen', 'garage', 'backDoor', 'milk', 'garage', 'frontDoor', 'manualKitchen', 
    'autokitchen', 'energyCom', 'alarm', 'weather', 'solar', 'sched', 'thermo', 'manualKitchen', 'backDoor', 'garage', 'window', 'frontDoor', 'autokitchen', 
    'manualKitchen', 'frontDoor', 'solar', 'garage', 'energyCom', 'alarm']

#Dictionary of what the above short names connect to. Take short names, and connect them to full length notifications
listOfNotificationText = {'garage': 'Your garage door has opened', 'frontDoor': 'Your front door has opened', 'backDoor': 'Your back door has opened', 
    'energyCom': 'Your daily energy consumption is: 33.5 kWh', 'thermo': 'Your thermostat has been changed to 73 degrees', 'weather': 'The weather for the day is: Cloudy and cool',
    'solar': 'The solar cell battery status is 52%', 'alarm': 'Tomorrow’s alarm is set for 9am', 'sched': 'Today’s schedule includes: ', 
    'milk': 'Don’t forget to get milk on your way home today.', 'manualKitchen': 'A light in the kitchen has been turned on', 
    'sensor': 'The sensor above the door is not responding.  Please check on its status.', 
    'tvenergy': 'Your television utilizes 2 watts of energy when not in use.  It will be powered off when not in use from now on.',
    'window': 'The bedroom window has been opened to cool the room.'}

#test code, can be used to test the notification system
time1 = now+timedelta(seconds=30)
time2 = now+timedelta(seconds=60)
time3 = now+timedelta(seconds=90)
testList = [dt.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, time1.hour, time1.minute, time1.second), 
    dt.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, time2.hour, time2.minute, time2.second), 
    dt.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, time3.hour, time3.minute, time3.second)]

#empty list to be filled
listOfTimeDelays = [0, 0, 0]

#takes all the lists above, and figures out how long each of them are from when I started the study.
#This creates a giant list of delays from the day I hit start
def calculateMinutesIntoSeconds(testList, listOfTimeDelays):
    i = 0
    for member in testList:
        print(member)
        listOfTimeDelays[i] = ((member-dt.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute, now.second)).total_seconds())
        print(listOfTimeDelays[i])
        i= i+1

# Note that you have to specify path to script
#This call runs the notification.

#Create a scheduler.
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

#Takes a notification text and sends ends out the notification.
def notification(notify='failure to properly fill notification'):
    call(["node", "app.js", notify, "send this data"])

#test code. Mostly ignore this
def print_time(a='default'):
    print("From print_time", time.time(), a)


def send_notifications():
    #calculate all of the many times delays
    calculateMinutesIntoSeconds(testList, listOfTimeDelays)
    # calculateMinutesIntoSeconds(listOfTimesDay1, listOfTimeDelays)
    # calculateMinutesIntoSeconds(listOfTimesDay2, listOfTimeDelays)
    # calculateMinutesIntoSeconds(listOfTimesDay3, listOfTimeDelays)
    # calculateMinutesIntoSeconds(listOfTimesDay4, listOfTimeDelays)
    # calculateMinutesIntoSeconds(listOfTimesDay5, listOfTimeDelays)

    print("Time marker for beginning of study: ", time.time())
    #counter needed for calls
    i = 0
    #Just notify people that the study has started.
    s.enter(5, 1, notification, kwargs={'notify': 'Welcome to the Study!'})
    #This for loop fills the scheduler with every notification that needs to be sent.
    for member in listOfTimeDelays:
        #takes one of the time delays, a priority (I just made them all 1), and then sends the right notification
        s.enter(member, 1, notification, kwargs={'notify': listOfNotificationText[listOfNotificationNames[i]]})
        #Incriments the counter to make sure you get the next notification
        i = i+1
    #runs the scheduler
    s.run()
    #Marks the end of the study
    print("Time marker for end of study: ",time.time())

#Calls the above method
send_notifications()
```

UPDATE:

Hmm, on further inspection, it looks like the Wheezy system defaults 3.2 and won't accept a request for anything higher than that. Looks like it accepts "argument" but as Klaus suggested, argument also needs notify to be in the same area as the sent notification.

So now it looks like

```
s.enter(5, 1, notification, argument={'notify: Welcome to the Study!'})
    #This for loop fills the scheduler with every notification that needs to be sent.
    for member in listOfTimeDelays:
        notification = 'notify: ' + listOfNotificationText[listOfNotificationNames[i]]
        #takes one of the time delays, a priority (I just made them all 1), and then sends the right notification
        s.enter(member, 1, notification, argument={notification)
        #Incriments the counter to make sure you get the next notification
        i = i+1
```

Thanks for the assistance with this.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same version of python in your Mac and in the server?

Comment: I guess you are using the `**kwargs` wrongly. It catches all "left over" named arguments. Instead of `kwargs`  give `notify=...` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sched.Scheduler` only accepts a `kwargs` argument [from Python 3.3 onwards](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html#sched.scheduler.enterabs). I guess you are running an older version on your Debian machine.

Comment: Hmm, on further inspection, it looks like the Wheezy system defaults 3.2 and won't accept a request for anything more. Look like it accepts "argument" but as Klaus suggested, it also needs notify to be in the same area as the ...